# Unable to activate virtualenv from Python script (subprocess | powershell)

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, virtualenv

This is pretty straightforward to activate a `virtualenv` from powershell of Windows, by `./venv/Scripts/activate` command, or with an absolute path like below:

[image: virtualenv]

But when I want to execute the same command from a Python script that executes commands in `powershell`, virtualenv doesn't activate and I can't run `pip install something` commands inside virtualenv. It means that I can't add packages or even upgrade pip inside virtualenv (Surely because it's not activated correctly).

**Note**

I'm confident about the implementation of the code because it works clearly for other commands. The only problem might be with `C:/temp/venv/Scripts/activate` command sent to powershell. Looking for some command like `source` in Linux to activate that virtualenv.

**Here is my code:**

`installer.py` script: runs different commands inside powershell with `subprocess`, and returns the result.

```
# installer.py
class Installer:
   def run(command):
        # Some code here
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            [ 'powershell.exe', command ],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        # Some code here
```

`install.py` script: sends commands to the Installer class

```
# install.py
from installer import Installer

installer = Installer()
installer.run('C:/temp/venv/Scripts/activate')
```

Comment: Your subprocess runs and activates the environment, then ends and loses the settings from the virtual environment. This is a common FAQ but I don't know off hand if there is a duplicate specifically for Powershell. The workaround is to activate the environment before running your Python script, or run the activatie command and the commands you want to execute inside the virtual environment as a single Powershell subprocess. Maybe `subprocess.run('path to activate\nmore commands...', shell=True, executable=r'c:\windows\horrors\abyss\hopelessness\confusion\insults\etc\powershell.exe')`

Comment: Maybe also try running `c:/temp/venv/bin/pip` directly; this works on Unix-like systems at least.

Comment: @tripleee I give it a try, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### SOLUTION

Turned out I didn't need to activate virtualenv. I could easily run `pip install` commands with following command sent to subprocess:

```py
installer.run('C:/temp/venv/Scripts/python.exe -m pip install somepackage')
```